# How to install a parser library for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting:

```
Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: parser.html. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

when ever I try to parse my page. Please for help for I am still not very good at python.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"parser.html")
questions = soup.select(".question-summary")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser should be "html.parser" and not "parser.html"

Refer to the beautiful soup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for details.

Comment: Please may you give the way to get only the text of questions[0]

Answer (score 1):

Use `'html.parser'` instead of `'parser.html'`. This may work.

If not, try: `"html5lib"`